# How to reverse a stringify function?

Tags: c#, encoding

I'm using a function to display a string value from a byte[].
In order to display text in my Grid.

Here the function that I use:

```
public static string Stringify(this byte[] b)
{
    return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(b);
}
```

The issue occurs when I want to save what I've modified or updated. It does not retrieve the string displayed from the byte[] but a string with illegal characters such as "C??N?s???C,7e??". So I can not save this data in DB, it raises me an Exception of illegal character entity.

I would like to know to get back the correct value instead of this akward string.

Thanks !

EDIT: 
Example of an output of BitConverter.ToString(b):

> "43-C4-5B-4B-EC-1F-10-36-E0-43-2C-37-65-03-10-36"

Comment: Are all the characters you're using actually ASCII?

Comment: Looks like an encoding issue

Comment: I was using Encoding.UTF8 before to post, but it does not work neither.

Comment: why don't you just save the output of `BitConverter.ToString(b);` to the db?

Comment: Because I save what I set in my GUI grid. And in the grid, the values displayed look like "350-400", "HGB", "CHICAGO", ... And when I save I retrieve akward string instead of the ones in my grid. Some fields of my DB table take varchar, not byte[]. I can not only send the output of BitConverter.

Comment: You need to show more code, because that data looks more like a part of an MD5 hash instead of "CHICAGO". Do you have any idea what `"43-C4-5B-4B-EC-1F-10-36-E0-43-2C-37-65-03-10-36"` should represent?

Comment: "43-C4-5B-4B-EC-1F-10-36-E0-43-2C-37-65-03-10-36" stands for "HBG". I'll see what can I add to help you guys.

Comment: So if you could store `43-C4-5B-4B-EC-1F-10-36-E0-43-2C-37-65-03-10-36` and later restore this data to the grid, would the grid show "HBG" "again?

Comment: I understood my mistake. It was because I used Stringify on fields which do not need reference to an ID. I used a ValueListItem(ID.Stringify(), TOWN), I changed this by ValueListItem(TOWN, TOWN). You put me on the way, thank you !

Answer (score -1):

Can you give an example of what you are giving as input in bytes and what you are getting in String?

Comment: THis isn't an answer, it's a question, and it should have been in a comment.